# How to sort tagged posts by newest first instead of unanswered?

Tags: support, tags, sorting

When I choose my favorite tag (`c#`) and click on it my browser goes to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

The title of page is "unanswered" and by default the selected tab is "unanswered".

I want to see all posts tagged C# ordered by *newest* first.

If I am not wrong this page shows me all posts instead of unanswered. If not then tell me the way I can see all posts instead of unanswered only.

Any suggestion to solve this puzzle?

Comment: Welcome to meta! :D :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to see all post who is C# tagged and order by new first.

You just need to change the tab you're on.

[image: tagged questions page tabs]

Comment: @TRiG how did you find the image? Might be useful for other broken pictures :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard. It was uploaded to a personal Imgur account (hence, `i.imgur.com`), back in the days when SE's images were also on `i.imgur.com`. When SE's images moved to `i.stack.imgur.com`, they did an auto change of existing images, which broke images which had been uploaded to personal accounts. Most of those have now been fixed. This was one of the stragglers.

Comment: @TRiG oh, so http://i.stack.imgur.com/tiaJc.png --> http://imgur.com/tiaJc.png - neat!